# How to develop a real time file upload with Angular 2 and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

Usually, while we upload it takes files to the temp directory first and then move it to the desired directory. But I'm working on Big Data e.g. uploading thousands of files at once. So I need to upload those files directly to the desired location and as each one of them uploaded to that directory, the user must see the changes on the dashboard in real time.

Also I need to show user

1. If any exception has occurred while uploading e.g. if a file causing a problem in the uploading process.
2. There should be an option to skip that file or retry upload.
   Report to show the list of files uploaded successfully vs files that failed to upload.
3. If there is any network outage, the upload manager should keep retrying until the network is restored.
4. User can pause upload and can restart it on next login(if it is feasible)

**This is about full manipulation of the upload process to give user the best user experience while uploading large sets of data.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload), it has most of the feature you require.

You can also find demo [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/).

For rest of the features you require, you can implement those on top of this library (It's better than writing your own code from scratch).